# Peculiar issue with quicksort partition

Tags: quicksort, partitioning

Today, when trying quicksort, instead of taking last element as pivot and partitioning,i took the first element as pivot, But it is not producing the correct partitioned output.

```
int pivot = ar[0];
int pindex = 0;

for(int  i = 0;i < ar.size();i++)
{
    if(ar[i] <= pivot)
    {
        swap(ar[i],ar[pindex]);
        pindex++;
    }
}
swap(ar[pindex],ar[ar.size()-1]);
```

I could not understand why, i always use this for partition, but this is not working when i take first element as partition.

But this worked even if i took first element as partition

```
int i, j, pivot, temp;
pivot = ar[0];
i = 0;
j = ar.size()-1;
while(1)
{
    while(ar[i] < pivot && ar[i] != pivot)
        i++;
    while(ar[j] > pivot && ar[j] != pivot)
        j--;
    if(i < j)
    {
        temp = ar[i];
        ar[i] = ar[j];
        ar[j] = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

What are the differences between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found that, this method is Hoare's partition method, where as the typical quick sort method we all follow is lomuto's partition.

See this wiki page, it has all details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort